# if checkbox is not checked it should not take its value and error should not be displayed

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have a coding. In that checkbox may or may not be checked, if it is checked there is no error if the checkbox is not checked then error occurs. can anyone give solution for this 
this is my html code for checkbox

```
<input name="cb" type="checkbox" id="set_2" value="20"/> Project<td><i class = "pro_hidden pro_option_set_2"> Included</i></td>
```

If the check box is checked it takes the value 20 and if not checked it will not take the value but it shows `Notice: Undefined index: cb`I also included javascript if the checkbox is checked it shows included. if not checked it displays nothing...the javascript coding s this

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">/script>
    <script>
  $('.pro_hidden').css({
'display': 'none'
 });

 $(':checkbox').change(function() {
var option = 'pro_option_' + $(this).attr('id');
if ($('.' + option).css('display') == 'none') {
    $('.' + option).fadeIn();
}
else {
    $('.' + option).fadeOut();
}
});
</script>
```

I am trying to add values:

```
<tr>
<td>duration</td>

<td><input type="text" name="duration" values=""> 

</td>
</tr>

<tr>
   <td><input type="radio" name="rd" value="2" required>2hrs</td>
   <td><input type="radio" name="rd" value="4" required>4hrs</td>
</tr>

 <tr>   
   <td>
<input name="cb" type="checkbox" id="set_2" value="20"> Project<td><i class = "pro_hidden pro_option_set_2">      20hrs Included</i></td>
    </td>
```

this is my entire code if this form is submitted it goes to next page and add the values using php

```
 <?php
 $du=$_POST['duration'];
 $cb=$_POST['cb'];
 $c=$_POST['rd'];
 $sum=($du+$cb)/$c;
 echo $sum;
 ?>
```

if checkbox is not checked it displays error here...if the checkbox is not checked how to give coding??

Comment: <input name="cb" type="checkbox" id="set_2" value="20"> Project
if checkbox is not checked it is showing error as **Notice: Undefined index: cb **

Comment: That's just the HTML. HTML is not really code. We need the code. And you should also tag the question with which programming language you are using (e.g. Javascript, if you are using Javascript).

Comment: @RobinGreen I edited my que and what extra coding you are expecting pls tell me clearly

Comment: If checkbox is not checked it doesn't have a value and therefor is not in your `$_POST` or `$_GET`. And you are trying to access the variable that doesn't exist.

Comment: @putvande you are assuming that user3132845 is using PHP. If that is so, user3132845 should tag the question with PHP.

Comment: @putvande i cant understand what u r saying??

Comment: Hi, I really can't understand what you are trying to accomplish.. are you working server side or client side? is there a form?? something isn't complete here..

Comment: That is a PHP error so show us the php part for the code

Answer (score 0):

If the checkbox is not checked, no value is passed. So before checkbox you have to place  with the same name and default value.

```
<input name="cb" value="default" type="hidden">
<input name="cb" type="checkbox" id="set_2" value="20">
```

Comment: this doesnt show error if it is not checked but before the checkbox default is displayed in a textbox

Answer (score 0):

When checkbox isn't checked, it is not submitted to the server and therefore undefined in PHP. You have to use `isset` function before accessing any `$_GET` or `$_POST` variable.

Instead of this

```
 $du = $_POST['duration'];
 $cb = $_POST['cb'];
 $c  = $_POST['rd'];
```

You should do this

```
if(isset($_POST['duration']))
      $du = $_POST['duration'];

if(isset($_POST['cb']))
      $cb = $_POST['cb'];

if(isset($_POST['rd']))
      $c = $_POST['rd'];
```

For more details refer to [documentation](http://www.php.net/isset).